# Quelle expression veut dire vendre une partie comme si c'était le tout ?

Tags: expressions

Je cherche une expression française ou à franciser qui veut dire qu'on fait croire qu'une partie d'une chose apporte les bénéfice du tout.
Par exemple :
**Vendre une roue comme si c'était une voiture**. *On ne peut pas faire avec une roue seule ce qu'on peut faire avec une voiture*.
**Vendre un haltère comme si c'était une salle de musculation.**
**Vendre des briques comme si c'était une maison.**
**Vendre une tenue de cosmonaute comme si c'était une fusée.**

Le cas réel à l'origine de ma question est la pratique de vendeurs de formations en ligne (ou de livres) qui vendent des **connaissances incomplètes** pour arriver à faire ce qu'ils promettent. Ce n'est pas la même chose qu'un produit miracle.

C'est la notion de bénéfices plus que celle de quantité qui est à exprimer. Vous pouvez me proposer des phrases de votre création si elles sont plus parlantes.

En anglais *buying/selling a pup* pourrait convenir, tout dépend de son équivalent en français.

Comment: @NoëlloMiqueron il pense qu'il peut se déplacer avec parce qu'il ne connait pas la voiture, on lui a montré une roue et vanté ses faux mérites

Comment: Vous voulez quelque chose avec le mot **vendre** ou pas?

Comment: @Lambie non ça pourrait être une recommandation trompeuse au lieu d'une transaction, la vente serait alors prise au sens large

Answer (score 2):

Une expression proche, au moins étymologiquement, puisque son explication la plus courante explique qu'il s'agissait à de vendre une vessie de porc ou de bœuf gonflée avec une bougie à l'intérieur et de faire prendre le tout pour une lanterne est :

> Faire prendre [des vessies pour des lanternes](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/prendre-des-vessies-pour-des-lanternes).

Sinon, beaucoup de verbes plus génériques peuvent inclure ce sens :

> Arnaquer
> Tromper (sur la marchandise)
> Duper
> Pigeonner
> Flouer

Comment: Dans la même veine : [prendre le Pirée pour un homme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/prendre_le_Pir%C3%A9e_pour_un_homme), croire au Père Noël.

Comment: @None Oui, on peut *faire croire au Père Noël* comme on peut *faire prendre des vessies pour des lanternes* mais ça me paraît moins pertinent pour *(faire?) prendre le Pirée pour un Homme* qui est plus le fait de la personne qui se trompe toute seule que d'un tiers qui lui fait croire autre chose que la vérité.

Answer (score 0):

Une expression proche : [vendre chat en poche](https://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/5497/vendre-chat-en-poche/).

Je suis tombé sur cette expression (qui semble plutôt vieillie) en cherchant "selling a pup", et c'est un [site de traduction de paroles](https://lyricstranslate.com/fr/idiom/sell-someone-pup) qui m'a proposé la version française.

L'expression est en fait plus proche de *[Pig in a poke](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pig_in_a_poke)*.